# Detecting all note head wether it is a whole note or half note

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need to detect all whole and half note from the [given image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CPFk.jpg) and print the all detected note into a new image. But it seems that the code does not detect the half note it only detects the whole note.

This is the source code I have

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    // Read image
    Mat im = imread("beethoven_ode_to_joy.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

    // Change thresholds
    params.minThreshold = 10;
    params.maxThreshold = 200;

    // Filter by Area.
    params.filterByArea = true;
    params.minArea = 25;

    // Filter by Circularity
    params.filterByCircularity = true;
    params.minCircularity = 0.1;

    // Filter by Convexity
    params.filterByConvexity = true;
    params.minConvexity = 0.87;

    // Filter by Inertia
    params.filterByInertia = true;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;


    // Storage for blobs
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;


#if CV_MAJOR_VERSION < 3   // If you are using OpenCV 2

    // Set up detector with params
    SimpleBlobDetector detector(params);

    // Detect blobs
    detector.detect(im, keypoints);
#else 

    // Set up detector with params
    Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);

    // Detect blobs
    detector->detect(im, keypoints);
#endif 

    // Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    // DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures
    // the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

    Mat im_with_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    // Show blobs
    imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: You have to understand that in CV, things aren't that simple... Such a simple approach cannot succeed, given the complex task you are requesting. You need to go more into details, analysing the image areas the descriptors are finding, and then classifying these into categories. But this is far beyond the scope of a SO question.

Comment: may i ask is there a way to detect the note head?

Comment: regardless of it being a whole note or half note, cause i;m trying to detect the note heads and print them to a new image.

Comment: Idea: use the descriptors to extract a small image around their location (say 32x32), validate them, then extract a rectangle of the expected tail size above, then check if there is a tail, then check on top of that line if full note or half note. A lot of code to write...

Comment: Voted to close as "too broad" because dumping C++ code and just saying "it doesn't work" is not productive.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I don't have openCV now.But I try something to solve this in matlab in short time.Firstly,[in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68OgO.jpg) you will realize that head of the notes are darker than staves.When we get more inside it we see that centers of the notes have 0 value [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcood.jpg) . I suggest you that you can convert yor RGB image to grayscale image, after that can apply thresholding.If the values of pixels is equal to 0 they're ok you should get them but if not you don't get them.Its result is here [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYPzP.jpg) .Then, I think you can apply some morphologic operations like dilation. Because detected head of notes will be a little bit smaller than original.If you want to eliminate the up side of notes(I mean stick part of notes) you can detect this part with hough line transformation, opencv has functions for this operation (HoughLines or houghLinesP).After detection you can delete this part or if you don't want, you can pass this step.After all, you can find circular objects on the image with hough transform.HoughCircles functions perform this task in opencv.In Matlab it is a little bit easier with findcircles function.Finally, you can draw founded circles with circle function in opencv or viscircles function in matlab.Result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrVcF.jpg)

Notice that I didn't apply morphologic operations to improve size of heads of notes.Also, I didn't apply houghline transformation to detect and erase stick parts.If you can apply them ,I think you will get better result.
This algorithm is only a suggestion,you can find better algorithm by trying some other operations.